# jqplot - Unwanted line at the left of the canvas

Tags: jqplot

Does anyone see the problem in my code why this border apears?
I know that asking for the solution of a problem is not "best practice" but I have wasted some hours already and could not fix it...
I'm sure its just a simple config problem I just can not see but someone with more practice in jqplot can find in a few seconds...

[image]

Here is the code I'm using:

```
jQuery.jqplot(this.getNonHasheContainerName(), chartDrawingData, {
    animate: false,
    seriesColors: barChartColors,
    seriesDefaults: barChartSeriesDefaults,
    grid: ChartGridDefaults,
    series: this.getBarChartSeriesLabels(chartMetadata.series),
    legend: barChartLegendDefaults,
    title: { show: false },
    axes: barChartAxisDefaults(ticks, chartMetadata.showGrid)
});

var barChartColors = ['#9FC0DF', '#EFAD81'];

var barChartSeriesDefaults = {
renderer: jQuery.jqplot.BarRenderer,
rendererOptions: {
    barMargin: 10,
    highlightMouseOver: true,
    animation:
        {
            speed: 2500
        }
},
pointLabels: { show: true },
shadow: false
};

var barChartLegendDefaults = {
show: true,
location: 'e',
placement: 'outsideGrid'
};

var barChartAxisDefaults = function (ticks, showGrid) {
return {
    xaxis: {
        show: false,
        renderer: jQuery.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
        tickRenderer: jQuery.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
        ticks: ticks,
        tickOptions: {
            angle: 45,
            fontSize: "11px",
            showGridline: false,
            showMark: true,
            //labelPosition: 'end',
            mark: 'inside',
            markSize: 10
        },
    },
    yaxis: {
        show: false,
        min: 0,
        tickOptions: {
            showMark: false,// showGrid,
            showLabel: false,// showGrid,
            showGridline: false,
            tickInterval: 1,
            formatString: '%d',
            //borderWidth: 1
        },
    },
    x2axis: {
        show: false
    },
    y2axis: {
        show: false
    }
};
};

var ChartGridDefaults = {
shadow: false,
background: '#ffffff',
borderWidth: 1,
drawGridlines: false,
drawBorder: false
};

var pieChartSeriesDefaults = {
renderer: jQuery.jqplot.PieRenderer,
rendererOptions: {
    showDataLabels: true,
    dataLabels: 'value',
    fill: true,
    sliceMargin: 2,
    lineWidth: 5
},
shadow: false
};

var pieChartLegendDefaults = {
show: true,
location: 'e'
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I HAVE GOT IT!!!

There is an other hidden (or i have overseen it in the documentation...) setting for the renderer:

```
yaxis: {
        show: false,
        min: 0,
        tickOptions: {
            showMark: false,// showGrid,
            showLabel: false,// showGrid,
            showGridline: false,
            tickInterval: 1,
            formatString: '%d',
        },
        **rendererOptions: {
            drawBaseline: false
        }**
    }
```